How are undefined colors in SVG files determined in Windows/Obsidian?
I want to change the color rendered in Windows when SVG elements are undefined. I use dark mode in everything and right now it is rendering in black on a dark gray screen, which makes it hard to see. I'd like it to be light gray or white.
Not sure if its a Windows level thing because the same colors are used in different applications. I am previewing with a VSCode extension and putting it in Obsidian.
I know I can change the colors for each element but that's a lot of work for the amount of elements I have for the SVG files I'm using (not the example I've attached). I'd like to be able to control it at a system or at least application level. Specifically, I want to use it in Obsidian for notes.[Code with RenderingObsidian Rendering](https://i.sstatic.net/fz3RETZ6.png)
I tried using CSS style sheets in Obsidian but couldn't get it to work. It may be that I just didn't have the right syntax.

Can you add a bit more info about what you tried in regard to the CSS style sheet.
